# route attribute not working mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

```
[RouteArea("Admin")]
[RoutePrefix("Post")]
public class PostController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Create")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new Post();
        return View(model);
    }
```

If i'll try to access Index action it works but at Create action it doesn't. (It gives me HTTP 404)

I've added routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); in RouteConfig.cs in App_Start folder

```
public class RouteConfig
 {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

but after that I'm getting an error

> A route named “Admin_default” is already in the route collection.

After that I need to remove that line and delete all DLL in bin folder, than rebuild project.

other I've left as it is. What's wrong?

Of course route in area is correct

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Admin_default",
            "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: If you are planning to only use Route Attributes, you don't need to make any calls to `MapRoute` at all. `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` handles all action methods, both in any Areas and as well as non-area controllers.

Comment: @NathanA I'm not using. I found that solution here and because mentioned. I've code without it and I'm getting 404 when trying this: http://localhost:51095/admin/post/create

Comment: I just did a recreation in a new MVC project, and it works as you have it.  There must be something else in there that is breaking it.

Comment: Yep. Nothing wrong with the code here. Something else is causing the problem.